# When reading excel files with pandas, what determines the datatype of the cells being read?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am reading an excel sheet and plucking data from rows containing the given PO.

```
import pandas as pd

xlsx = pd.ExcelFile('Book2.xlsx')
df = pd.read_excel(xlsx)
PO_arr = ['121121','212121']

for i in PO_arr:
    PO = i
    PO_DATA = df.loc[df['PONUM'] == PO]

    for i in range(1, max(PO_DATA['POLINENUM'].values) +1):
```

When I take this Excel sheet straight from its source, my code works fine. But when I cut out only the rows I want and paste them to a new spreadsheet with the exact same formatting and read this new spreadsheet, I have to change PO_DATA to look for an integer instead of a string as such:

```
PO_DATA = df.loc[df['PONUM'] == int(PO)]
```

If not, I get an error, and calling PO_DATA returns an empty dataframe.

```
C:\...\pandas\core\ops\array_ops.py:253: FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
res_values = method(rvalues)
```

I checked the cell formatting in Excel and in both cases, they are formatted as 'General' cells.

What is going on that makes it so when I chop up my spreadsheet, I have to look for an integer and not a string? What do I have to do to make it work for sheets I've created and pasted relevant data into instead of only sheets from the source?

Comment: This might be impossible to replicate without sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Excel can do some funky formatting when copy and paste is used: ctl-c : ctl-v.
I am sure you tried these but...

A) Try copy ctl-c then ctl-alt-v:"v":enter ... on new sheet/file

B) Try using the format painter in Excel : Looks like a paintbrush on the home tab - select the properly formatted cells first - double click format painter - move to your new file/sheet - select cells you want the format to conform to.

C) Select your new file/table you pasted into - select purple eraser icon from the top options in excel - clear all formats

Answer (score 0):

Update: I found an old related thread that didn't necessarily answer the question but solved the problem.

you can force pandas to import values as a certain datatype when reading from excel using the converters argument for read_excel.

```
df = pd.read_excel(xlsx, converters={'POLINENUM':int,'PONUM':int})
```